# Logic behind finding Heap space available

Tags: c, linux, memory-management

Hi i'm a new to memory management,
           i just thought of finding the logic to find the free heap space. I feel that by finding difference between "**program break**" and "**stack pointer**" we can get it is it correct? if not please justify and let me know the right logic.

Comment: Try `cat /proc/self/maps`  or `cat /proc/1234/maps`  for an interesting process of pid 1234.

Answer (score 2):

Memory layout under Linux is a complex beast and to my opinion you should usually not care about available heap: this is one of the purpose of virtual memory. Every process sees a flat large memory space.

Regarding your propose solution, I don't think it is correct because as described here: http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/anatomy-of-a-program-in-memory/ the hep grows up starting at the end of BSS segment.

You can easily get the heap size for a process (22088 in this example) from a terminal with:

```
cat /proc/22088/maps | grep heap
7f5082180000-7f5082ac7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]
```

From C user space code, you can read at this file to get the heap size of the current process.

Comment: Hi Manuel,is there any system call that returns amount of heap space available.I need to write an api in c(Linux) to find the heap space available.

Comment: No such system call doesn't exist. You'll have to read the file /proc/self/maps from your C code using fopen and fread to get this information.

Comment: Hi Manuel,this shows the mapping of heap memory (or) total heap memory.Is there any way to get free heap space(amount of unallocated heap space).

Comment: Reading this file and knowing exactly how memory is laid out you should be able to compute free heap = 2^64 - all other areas But why do you need such in formation ? If you plan to allocate such a large amount of memory you are going to swap a lot

Comment: I have been asked to do this sanity checking before starting the application,this app. requires min. 200 mb.I checked the device there was no swap partition(using free command)i think RAM space will be high.

Comment: Ok. So just to clarify, on a 64 bits system each process sees 2^64 bytes of virtual memory which is about 18*10^18 (a very large number).  So you will just check that your process is below the limit

Comment: After process has began i have to check the unallocated heap space available which should be min. of 200 mb.If it its greater than (or) equal to 200 mb. i will continue else i have to try after some time.

Comment: 2^64(Process address space) - all other areas(except heap) will give u total heap space only this should be doing for before i allocate any space on heap.If i need to calculate the free heap space after some malloc's how do i do it.

Comment: I came across like there is a linked list maintained by malloc for both allocated and unallocated space,can we find something using this logic?

Comment: How to confirm the address space range allocated for each process,why am i asking is this code sits in diff. platform the address space range may vary.So please let me know how to find address space range of process

Comment: My /proc/maps Output:  35aa39c000-35aa3a1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00    0  what does this print means("0")?,does this means to free space?.

Comment: 023ec000-0240d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0       [heap]  
This is the heap space allocated for my sample code.If i find the difference b/w the mapped address it will be heap space allocated right.Please correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: This the virtual part of the heap space only. When you do malloc (100Gigas) you are virtually allocating memory, even if you system has only two gigas of memory free could report you 1,3 gigas as available. memory is physically allocated only on the first page fault when memory is effectively accessed.